# Dynamic statement in python to plot graph when one entity is varying

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have to plot graph between 3 entities- "Server_names", "Year", and "Exception_count":

Server names are stores in list :

```
Server_names=['s1','s2','s3']
```

Number of years are also stored in list:

```
Year=['2013','2014']
```

The Exception_count for the combination of one server name and one year is stored in dictionary and varies if the number of server and number of years varies.

```
Exception_count:{ 
                  1:[40,30,20],     # 40(S1 and 2012), 30(s2 and 2012), 20(s3 and 2012)
                  2:[10,40,40]      # 10(s1 and 2013), 40(s2 and 2013), 40(s3 and 2013)
                 }
```

"So you see If my servernames or number of year increase the dictionary content will increase too"

The graph I want to plot looks like:
    [image]

I have tried the code But the code is limited for Exception_count two inputs:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=tuple([40,30,20])            # a is extracted from the Exception_count with key 1
b=tuple([10,40,40])            # b is extracted from the Exception_count with key=2
c=tuple(Server_names)          #Server_names=['server_1','server_2','server_3']
d=tuple(Year)                  #Year=['2013','2014']


width=0.35
range_ab=np.arange(len(a))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

y_axis = ax.bar(range_ab, a, width, color='y')
y_axis2= ax.bar(range_ab+width, b, width, color='r')

ax.set_xticks(range_ab+width)
ax.set_xticklabels(c)

ax.legend((y_axis[0], y_axis2[0]),d)

plt.show()
```

The above code gives me the output as desired but its not dynamic. If the Key, value for Exception_count increases The output wouldn't be as desired.

Can any body suggest me how to write dynamic queries in python. Or any different method from which I can create the above graph from the given inputs (Server_names, Year, Exception_count)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#changes here
server_names=['s1','s2','s3','s4']
exception_count = { 
                  '2012':[40,30,20,10],
                  '2013':[10,40,40,15],
                  '2014':[20,70,10,30]
                 }

#fixed part
year= sorted(exception_count.keys())
sN = len(server_names)
yN = len(year)

colors = { y:(rd.rand(),rd.rand(),rd.rand()) for y in year}

ind=np.arange(sN)
width=0.8/float(yN)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

rects = [ ax.bar(ind + i*width, exception_count[y], width, color=colors[y]) for (i,y) in enumerate(year)]

ax.set_xticks(ind + yN*width/2.0)
ax.set_xticklabels(server_names)

ax.legend(rects,year)

plt.show()
```